# Prove that $\sqrt{(1+1/n)}$ is irrational for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

I have trouble solving this probably simple problem:

> Prove that $\sqrt{1+1/n}$ is irrational for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Suppose not and derive a contradiction is usually the method for questions like this. That is, suppose that there exists integers $p, q$ such that $\sqrt{1+1/n} = p/q$ and show that that leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Good questions here usually show what you've tried and where you are stuck. Please edit yours to provide that information and you're more likely to get help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}}{n}
$$
so this is equivalent to proving that $\sqrt{n^2+n}$ is irrational, which is simpler, because, for a positive integer $m$, $\sqrt{m}$ is rational if and only if $m$ is a perfect square (prove it).

Moreover $n^2+n>n^2$ and…

Comment: Well, $\sqrt(m)$ is irrational, when m is not perfect square, because otherwise $m=p^2/q^2$ wouldn't be integer.  I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $1+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n+1}{n}$. Now suppose such a square root was rational, then there exist $a,b>0$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ such that 
$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}=\frac{n+1}{n}.$$
Now $\gcd(a^2,b^2)=\gcd(n+1,n)=1$ and since reduction of fractions to lowest terms happens in a unique way we obtain $a^2=n+1$ and $b^2=n$, but no two nonzero squares are one apart.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way.

$\sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} = \sqrt{\frac {n+1}{n}} = \sqrt{\frac {n(n+1)}{n^2}}= \frac 1n \sqrt{n(n+1)}$ which rational if and only if $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ is rational.

Square roots of integers are rational only when that are integer square roots of perfect squares.  So $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ is rational only if $n(n+1)$ is a perfect square.

But if $n > 0$ (which it must be if $n$ is natural $\frac 1n$ is defined) then:

$n^2 = n*n < n*(n+1) < (n+1)(n+1) = (n+1)^2$.

If $n*(n+1) = k^2$ then $n < k < n+1$ and $k$ can not be an integer so $n(n+1)$ is not a perfect square.

[The exceptions are $n = 0$ or $n = -1$ then $n(n+1) = 0^2$.  There reason the argument hold is if $n= 0$ then $n*n = n*(n+1) < (n+1)(n+1)$ so $n \le k < n+1$ so $k = n = 0$. or if $n = -1 < 0$ and $n+1 = 0$  $n*n > n*(n+1) = (n+1)(n+1)$ and so $k = n+1 = 0$.]

======

Ooooh..... this is cute:

Let $(1 +\frac 1n ) = \frac {a^2}{b^2}; a, b\in \mathbb Z; \gcd(a,b) = 1;b \ne 0$

Then $b^2(1 + \frac1n) = a^2$

$(b^2 - a^2) = \frac {b^2}{n}$.

$(b-a)(b+a) = \frac {b^2}{n}\in \mathbb Z$.

Let $p|\frac {b^2}{n}$ then $p|b$. But as $a,b$ are relatively prime. $p\not |b \pm a$ so $p\not \mid \frac {b^2}{n}$ after all and $\frac {b^2}{n} = 1$

$(b-a)(b+a) = 1$ so $(b-a) = (b+a) = \pm 1$ and $a = 0;(b = \sqrt{n})$ and $1 + \frac 1n = 0$.  Which is not possible.